# Set minimum number of rows on angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I'm trying to display an angular mat table with a minimum height. If there is no data available, I'd like it to simply show empty rows.

I've seen this article [Angular Material Table set default number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56988286/angular-material-table-set-default-number-of-rows)

But I won't know the number of rows as the display is responsive. Has anyone solved this yet? I haven't found anything yet.

**EDIT**
It seems maybe I wasn't clear on the question as all of the answers don't really fit.

I would like to be able to have a response sized div or container (maybe the table element itself). The container will grow and shrink vertically if the page size is changed vertically. THe number of rows visible (whether there is data available for them or not) should also increase or decreased based on the available table/container height

Thanks

Comment: What if there are only 1 or 2 rows? Do you want them to stretch to the height of the table?

Comment: No, I would like the table to be a responsive height, and the number of rows increased or decreased based on what would be needed to fill the height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

ts

```
getData() {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(r => {
    const minLength = window.innerHeight / x; // x is your row height
    if (!r) {
      r = new Array(minLength);
    } else {
      if (r.length < minLength) {
        r.push(...new Array(minLength - r.length))
      }
    }
    this.dataSource.data = r;
  });
}
```

Note: to use this I recommend you to use safe navigation operator:

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator

If your API is always returning an array, and if there's no data it returns [], you can remove the first if else.

```
getData() {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(r => {
    const minLength = window.innerHeight / x; // x is your row height
    if (r.length < minLength) {
      r.push(...new Array(minLength - r.length))
    }
    this.dataSource.data = r;
  });
}
```

Comment: As mentioned though, I don't know the number of rows. I would like the table to have a responsive height and the number of rows to increase or decrease based on the table height whether there is data available for the or not

Comment: Oh, alright. You can make your minRows based on window.innerWidth, like this:
minRows = window.innerHeight / x
where x is your row height of your mat-table. If you want to resize everytime the view size changes you can add a @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event''])

Comment: Ok, looking at the API I didn't see anything built in so assumed that I might have to do something like this. Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious though. My application is a desktop application so I want the table to fill the available height such as in a maximized desktop app. probably a little bit different idea than the web where generally you want it to take up as little space as possible

Comment: Yea, but there's not a way to get the height from the desktop app? Should work the same way, just replace window.innerHeight

Comment: Sure, I can do something like that, just wanted to be sure there wasn't a simpler way that wasn't already out there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the minimum 5 rows blank by default if the data is 1 then set the blank rows count to 4 by checking the amount of data roews present

Answer (score 0):

First set the mat-table pagination values, with the first value in "pageSizeOptions" being your default amount of displayed rows.

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Doing this you will always show 5 rows on each page, as we specified above.

This is a code example how you could go about generating "dummy" data if your dynamic data is empty

```
    private getData() {
       const EMPTY_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
          {position: null, name: null, weight: null, symbol: null},
          {position: null, name: null, weight: null, symbol: null},
          {position: null, name: null, weight: null, symbol: null},
          {position: null, name: null, weight: null, symbol: null},
          {position: null, name: null, weight: null, symbol: null}
       ];

       this.dataSource.data = EMPTY_DATA;
       this.dataService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
          if (!data) return;
          this.dataSource.data = data;
    }
```

Comment: I an not currently using pagination and didn't plan to as I want the table to scroll. I'm stil lnot sure this would work. If you only had two data items in your source but a min page size of five, it would still only show two rows, wouldn't it? It would not show the two rows plus blank rows to fill the table height as I would like

Comment: @kamcknig If you use pagination my example will work. And yes, if you have default page size of 5 but the dynamic data is only 2 rows, it would only show 2 rows. Since my code example overwrites the "dummy rows", only the dynamic data would be showing in the data table. The "default page size" is only to set **maximum** number of displayed rows per page